# TextBox inside a listview cell

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, celltemplate

I have a listview that I would like to add a textbox inside each gridview column cell so I can type data into it and then fetch that data.

I'm creating a datatemplate and passing it to a cell template for the GridViewColumn but when I look at the listview I can't add anything to the cell. It doesn't look like the textbox was even created.

```
            GridViewColumn conceptColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            conceptColumn.Header = conceptName;

            conceptColumn.CellTemplate = this.GetDataTemplate();
            this.TestModeler.Columns.Add(conceptColumn);
            conceptColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(conceptName);


    private DataTemplate GetDataTemplate()
    {
        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextBox));
        FrameworkElementFactory txtElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        dt.VisualTree = txtElement;

        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
        bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        txtElement.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
        txtElement.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "test");

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [ListView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) page at MSDN where you can find a XAML example and plenty of link on how to do various things with a WPF `ListView`.

Of particular interest to you, please take a look at the [How to: Use Templates to Style a ListView That Uses GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750709.aspx) page there which explains what you are trying to do (but in XAML) with examples.

MSDN should *always* be your first place to look as it is *full* of information just waiting to be read.